# Css for images stopped working

Tags: html, css, image

I made two pictures sit to the right of the big box with text. Everything looked fine until I re-opened the preview. The two pictures are now sitting full sized at the bottom of the page.
No matter what I write into my css file, they won't move a bit or they will disappear completely.

```css
* {
  font-family: Verdana
}
html {
  background-color: #e5f2ff
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 12em;
  background-color: #666666;
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: 0em 0em 2em 0em #666666
}
li img {
  display: block;
  width: 9em;
  height: 9em;
  margin: auto;
  border: 0.2em solid #e5f2ff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 3em;
  padding: 0.3em
}
li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 1em 0em 1em 0em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  border-bottom: 0.15em solid #e5f2ff
}
.bot {
  border: 0
}
a:hover {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding-bottom: 0.5875em;
  padding-top: 0.5875em
}
a:active {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 0.8em;
  border: 0
}
a:link {
  color: white
}
a:visited {
  color: white
}
#info {
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 6em 0em 10em 15em;
  border: 0.15em solid black;
  background-color: white;
  width: 35em;
  float: left
}
#sidenote {
  font-size: 0.7em
}
/* everything under here stopped working */

table {
  float: right;
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  margin: 4.9em 4em 1em 1em;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: underline
}
tr img {
  width: 12em;
  height: 12em;
  padding: 1em;
  border-radius: 100%;
  margin: 1em
}
#under {
  padding: 0em;
  margin: 0
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xft1/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/11420815_1616482671902240_1477475889_n.jpg" />
  </li>
  <li> <a href="https://happybone.se" class="top"> Start </a>
  </li>
  <li> <a href="https://giftigt.happybone.se" class="top"> Giftigt </a> 
  </li>
  <li> <a href="https://forum.happybone.se" class="top"> Forum </a>
  </li>
  <li> <a href="https://kontakt.forum.se" class="bot"> Kontakt </a>
  </li>
</ul>



<div id="info">
  <h3>Välkommen till happybone!</h3>
  <br>
  <p>Här på happybone vill vi underlätta för alla hundägare, nya som gamla.</p>
  <p>Vi erbjuder ett flertal roliga och lättnavigerade sidor. Vi har ett forum där du har möjlighet att diskutera med oss på happybone eller andra passionerade hundägare. Eller varför inte ordna upp en hundträff i en av Sveriges hundratals hundparker?</p>
  <p>Du navigerar i panelen till vänster om denna text.</p>
  <p>Där hittar du flikarna Start, Giftigt, Forum och Kontakt</p>
  <p>Klicka på en utav flikarna för mer information.</p>
  <p>Vi vill att du ska trivas här på happybone, hör därför gärna av dig till oss på info@happybone.se om det är något du undrar över.</p>
  <br>
  <br>
  <p id="sidenote">Sidan är under konstruktion, tack för ditt tålamod.</p>
</div>

<table>
  <tr>Veckans Bilder</tr>
  <tr>
    <img src="https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xft1/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/11420815_1616482671902240_1477475889_n.jpg" />
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <img id="under" src="https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xft1/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/11420815_1616482671902240_1477475889_n.jpg" />
  </tr>
</table>
```

I'd be forever greatful for your help. Thanks!

Comment: Is the CSS loaded at all? Did you edit the file, which you also use for testing (i.e. on the correct machine)? Can you see any other CSS rules in you browsers dev tools? Does the selector for the images match?

Comment: yes, everything else except the css for the two pictures works. The weird thing is that everything worked fine until I reopened the preview.

Comment: The problem is that I want the images to the right of the box with text. with border-radius:100%

Comment: table rows need a `td` as a child, your html is invalid

Comment: I tried that @Pete but it made the images dissapear. That's why I removed them

Comment: @K33n4, I'd use a div then otherwise as I say, your code is invalid and you will be penalised by some search engines.  Besides tables are only for tabular data and the way you are using it seems to be semantically incorrect

Comment: Ok, so you think I should insert The images separate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<del>I had to actually change the HTML, the only CSS I changed was the deleting the float on the imgs then using left: 10em;</del>

It's the floats and the huge margins placed on elements. By default 1em = 16px;

Wrapped a flexbox around the text and imgs.

Minimized the margins.

Made all elements `box-sizing:border-box;` so all measurements included, padding, borders, etc...

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; font-family: Verdana }

html { background-color: #e5f2ff }

ul { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 12em; background-color: #666666; text-align: center; position: fixed; height: 100%; top: 0; left: 0; box-shadow: 0em 0em 2em 0em #666666 }

li img { display: block; width: 9em; height: 9em; margin: auto; border: 0.2em solid #e5f2ff; border-radius: 100%; margin-top: 1em; margin-bottom: 3em; padding: 0.3em }

li a { display: block; padding: 1em 0em 1em 0em; text-decoration: none; color: white; font-size: 1.1em; border-bottom: 0.15em solid #e5f2ff }

.bot { border: 0 }

.box { display: flex; width: 100vw; height: 100vh; justify-content: center; position: relative; left: 3em;}

a:link { color: white }

a:visited { color: white }

a:hover { font-weight: bold; color: white; font-size: 1.5em; padding-bottom: 0.5875em; padding-top: 0.5875em }

a:active { font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.5em; background-color: black; padding: 0.8em; border: 0 }

#info { padding: 1em; border: 0.15em solid black; background-color: white; width: 50vw; height: 75vh; margin: 3em 0 0 0; }

#sidenote { font-size: 0.7em }

/* everything under here stopped working */


table {  position: relative; text-align: center; font-size: 1.1em; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; width: 25vw; height: 75vh; }

tr img { width: 200px; height: 200px; padding: 1em; border-radius: 100%; }


#under { padding: 0em; margin: 0 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Happybone</title>
<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
    <li>
        <img src="https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xft1/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/11420815_1616482671902240_1477475889_n.jpg"/>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="https://happybone.se" class="top"> Start </a></li>
    <li> <a href="https://giftigt.happybone.se" class="top"> Giftigt </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="https://forum.happybone.se" class="top"> Forum </a></li>
    <li> <a href="https://kontakt.forum.se" class="bot"> Kontakt </a></li>
</ul>
<section class="box">
<div id="info">
    <h3>Välkommen till happybone!</h3>
    <br>
    <p>Här på happybone vill vi underlätta för alla hundägare, nya som gamla.</p>
    <p>Vi erbjuder ett flertal roliga och lättnavigerade sidor. Vi har ett forum där du har möjlighet att diskutera med oss på happybone eller andra passionerade hundägare. Eller varför inte ordna upp en hundträff i en av Sveriges hundratals hundparker?</p>
    <p>Du navigerar i panelen till vänster om denna text.</p>
    <p>Där hittar du flikarna Start, Giftigt, Forum och Kontakt</p>
    <p>Klicka på en utav flikarna för mer information.</p>
    <p>Vi vill att du ska trivas här på happybone, hör därför gärna av dig till oss på info@happybone.se om det är något du undrar över.</p>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p id="sidenote">Sidan är under konstruktion, tack för ditt tålamod.</p>
</div>
<table>
    <tr><td><h1>Veckans Bilder</h1></td></tr>
    <tr>
<td>
        <img src="https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xft1/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/11420815_1616482671902240_1477475889_n.jpg"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>

        <td><img id="under" src="https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xft1/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/11420815_1616482671902240_1477475889_n.jpg"/></td>

    </tr>
</table>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Opps, it's late where I live. I will change the position to the right of text

Comment: Any ideas on why the css wouldn't work when the html order was different?

Comment: Mainly because floats are fragile and it takes more effort to balance them than it would be for more modern solutions like flexbox.

Comment: Ah ok! I'm teaching myself html and css so I misunderstand some things sometimes.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time! I'll read about the flex box

Comment: Pete is right about misuse of tables, invalid markup, and semantics. But those concerns are not as important as your knowledge of HTML and CSS use in layouts. That other stuff will fall into place as you practice and learn. Flexbox is advanced CSS, so play around with it but don't loose sight of the fundamentals.

Comment: Ok, I will keep on practicing. What should I use tables for? Is it ok to use it in the navbar at least?

Comment: It's ok to use tables the way your'e using them now, because it simply works. As you become more savvy, you will be using `display: table` instead. The reason using table in layout is frowned upon, is because it's purpose is to display data. It matters most for sight challenged people who rely on screen readers to interpret webpages for them. A screen reader will see the table tag and read it as data cells. It's very confusing for screen readers and their users. Also, if you practice semantics (use of the tags for what they basically are intended for), your code will be easier to understand.

Comment: Ah ok, I understand that now.

Comment: No problem, if this helped you click the green checkmark.